# weird behaviour of console.log between 2 different (but same content) field in the same object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to develop an application with geoLocation concept. I hit a brick and while I was trying to solve a problem, I encountered this issue.

This is a part of the main object, which i tried to write its contents to the console with **console.log()**.

```
{
    loc: '[object Object]',
    geometry: { location: { lat: 60.983218, lng: 19.063655 } }
}
```

the **loc** part is also contains same kind of values. but I can't see its contents when I tried.

Could someone tell the difference between this **'[object Object]'** and **{...}** issue?

It seems, it is related to JavaScript, but I couldn't figure it out

Comment: look like `loc` is actually a result of `Object.prototype.toString()`

Comment: what should I do while setting the **loc** variable? I am trying to copy what inside **geometry** is to the **loc** part.

Comment: By the way, I can see what it contains when I save it to a mongoDB collection.

Comment: check `typeof loc`. I think it's a string

Comment: (typeof loc) says **string**, but when I look at it in the Robomongo, I see <<loc:{"type" : "Point","coordinates" : "39.0658,19.0658"}>>

If this string contains **"[object Object]"** chars, how could I see different values for it in the collection? I am frustrated :|

Comment: Please show us your code that generates the object and logs it. It's quite possible that there are some issues when `loc` is a non-native mongoDB object. If it's a mongoDB thing, try to call `.toObject()` on it.